# How to update a stack navigator if its properties change?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, stack-navigator

The situation is the following, suppose I have this component.

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation: { navigate } }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(somedata)
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the home screen of the app</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: data.name})
        }
        title="Go to Brent's profile"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This component has a function that automatically updates the state when it changes in the database, (which I did not place, since it is only an example) and it works correctly, because when printing from the console, I realize that the component " HomeScreen" is rendered again, the problem is that when I navigate to the "Profile" component and update in the database, the "Profile" component is not rendered again or update then, however if the "HomeScreen" component is updated. How can I do to that somehow send a signal to the "Profile" component and it can be updated with the data from the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need updated data and for that

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation: { navigate } }) {
      const [data, setData] = useState(somedata);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    //Console.log(data); 
    // Here you'll get updated data and solve your issue.
  },[data]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is the home screen of the app</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: data.name})
        }
        title="Go to Brent's profile"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: That was done, the data is updated, so the "HomeScreen" component is updated again, however, since the update happens when I'm in the "Profile" component, I need it to be updated that component, which it doesn't... The normal behavior is supposed to be for the parent component to render, and the parent component to send a signal to the child components to render again.